# resolving actual runtime type of generic parameter rather than inferred type

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, casting, parametric-polymorphism

First, setup

```
interface IRequirement { }
interface ITarget { ICollection<IRequirement> Requirements { get; set; } }
interface IRequirementHandler<TRequirement, TTarget>
    where TRequirement : IRequirement
    where TTarget : ITarget {}

class AgeMustBeGreaterThanThirtyRequirement : IRequirement {}
class Person : ITarget { int Age { get; set; } }
class PersonAgeMustBeGreaterThanThirtyRequirementHandler : 
    IRequirementHandler<AgeMustBeGreaterThanThirtyRequirement, Person> {}
```

```
// register requirement handler in DI
    services.AddSingleton
      <IRequirementHandler<AgeMustBeGreaterThanThirtyRequirement, Person>,
        PersonAgeMustBeGreaterThanThirtyRequirementHandler>();
```

Basically I have target entities, requirements, and requirements handlers. a requirement can be applied to multiple target entities. a requirement handler handles a concrete requirement against a target.

All ITarget entities have a collection of `IRequirement`

```
interface ITarget { ICollection<IRequirement> Requirements { get; set; } }
```

I have a manager class that serves as service locator using .NET `IServiceProvider`, to resolve concrete handler for each requirement.

```
interface IRequirementHandlerLocator 
{ 
    IRequirementHandler<TRequirement, TTarget> GetHandler<TRequirement, TTarget>()
        where TRequirement : IRequirement
        where TTarget : ITarget
}
```

this is where I realized how ignorant I am in the topic of generics and types in general. I could not implement `IRequirementHandlerLocator` as it is, so I had to change it to

```
interface IRequirementHandlerLocator 
{ 
    IRequirementHandler<TRequirement, TTarget> GetHandler<TRequirement, TTarget>(TRequirement requirement, 
        TTarget target) where TRequirement : IRequirement
                        where TTarget : ITarget
}
```

and implemented it this way

```
class RequirementHandlerLocator : IRequirementHandlerLocator
{
    IRequirementHandler<TRequirement, TTarget> GetHandler<TRequirement, TTarget>(TRequirement requirement, 
        TTarget target) where TRequirement : IRequirement
                        where TTarget : ITarget
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequirementHandler<TRequirement, TTarget>>();
    }
}
```

I thought to myself, this way generic types are infered when I call `GetHandler()`. for example:

```
ITaskRequirementHandlerLocator _requirementHandlerLocator;
bool DoesTargetSatisfyRequirements(ITarget target)
{
    foreach (var requirement in target.Requirements)
    {
        var handler = _requirementHandlerLocator.GetHandler(requirement, target);
        if (!handler.QualifyAgainst(target))
          return false;
    }
}
```

Those who have good understanding of the topic know that this failed. because although `TRequirement` actual runtime type was `AgeMustBeGreaterThanThirtyRequirement` it was resolved as `IRequirement`, the full resolved type => `IRequirementHandler<IRequirement, ITarget>`. and registration in DI was

```
// register requirement handler in DI
    services.AddSingleton
      <IRequirementHandler<AgeMustBeGreaterThanThirtyRequirement, Person>,
        PersonAgeMustBeGreaterThanThirtyRequirementHandler>();
```

so DI container did not find the type
I learnt (and I am assuming) that generics captures/infers the given type rather than the actual runtime type. and since that I dont know the actual type in compile time =>

I need your help to solve this riddle, and perhaps add some information for me and those like me to deeper understand the issue.

EDIT:
I asked microsoft's bing chatGPT like service about this. and it suggested

```
var handlerType = typeof(ITaskRequirementHandler<,>)
    .MakeGenericType(typeof(TRequirement), typeof(TTarget));

//success. DI resolved the handler.
var handler = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);

//failure. casting failed.
return (IRequirementHandler<TRequirement, TTarget>) handler;
```

although the suggestion made resolved the correct handler type and DI returned the handler. but I could not cast it to the method signature.

Comment: Generic types in .Net still resolve at compile time, rather than run time.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I see. but there is a solution that I am blind/ignorant to find. library makers do it everywhere, but I am yet to understand their code.

Comment: If you are trying to determine the actual type in a generic method then you're probably doing it wrong. The whole point of generics is that they are generic, i.e. they work for any type that can be passed in. If you're writing type-specific code then that defeats the purpose of generics.

Comment: And if you are receiving the wrong type at runtime this might be a DI container problem rather than a generics problem.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I see your point. I believe I can use generics till the point of actually resolving the desired type from the DI container. at that point I should read the actual runtime type and resolve the desired type from the DI accordingly, then cast it back and return.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes it isn't. the DI is asked to resolve IRequirementHandler<IRequirement, ITarget>, and no registered service matches that. rather IRequirementHandler<AgeExceedThirtyRequirement, Person> is registered.

Comment: Is the list of `Requirements` really different from instance to instance, or do, for instance, all `Person` instances have the same exact same list of requirements? If so, your model can be simplified a lot.

Comment: @Steven yes every instance has different set of requirements. ITarget is actually an application (like when you apply for a driving license) that is driven by a workflow with steps, where each step has set of requirements to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're always passing `IRequirement` and `ITarget` at compile time as generic type arguments, the generic type arguments of `IRequirementHandlerLocator` become redundant. Therefore, I propose changing that abstraction to the following:

```cs
interface IRequirementHandlerLocator 
{ 
    IRequirementHandler<IRequirement, ITarget> GetHandler(
        IRequirement requirement, ITarget target);
}
```

In this case, your `RequirementHandlerLocator` should become:

```cs
class RequirementHandlerLocator : IRequirementHandlerLocator
{
    IRequirementHandler<IRequirement, ITarget> GetHandler(
        IRequirement requirement, ITarget target)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IRequirementHandler<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(requirement.GetType(), target.GetType());

        object handler = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);

        return (IRequirementHandler<IRequirement, ITarget>)handler;
    }
}
```

There's only one problem here and that's that the last cast in `RequirementHandlerLocator` will cause a runtime exception, stating that:

> Unable to cast object of type 'PersonAgeMustBeGreaterThanThirtyRequirementHandler' to type 'IRequirementHandler`2[IRequirement,ITarget]'.'

That's because the interface is not variant and an `IRequirementHandler<IRequirement, ITarget>` is not the same as an `IRequirementHandler<AgeMustBeGreaterThanThirtyRequirement, Person>`. For them to become interchangable, you have to make `IRequirementHandler<R, T>` covariant. In other words, you have to add the `out` keyword to the generic type constraints. In other words:

```cs
interface IRequirementHandler<out TRequirement, out TTarget>
    where TRequirement : IRequirement
    where TTarget : ITarget
{
}
```

Such change, however, will only work when both generic type arguments are only used as output arguments. Your question doesn't mention this, but this will probably not be the case. This means that you will not get your code to work, whatever you try. Why this is the case is too work to explain here, but Eric Lippert has great introduction blog posts on generic typing, variance, covariance, and contravariance.

A way around this is to let `IRequirementHandler<R, T>` inherit from a non-generic base type, e.g.:

```cs
interface IRequirementHandler { }

interface IRequirementHandler<out TRequirement, out TTarget>
    where TRequirement : IRequirement
    where TTarget : ITarget
    : IRequirementHandler
{
}
```

This way `IRequirementHandlerLocator` can return `IRequirementHandler` instead. There are possibly other solutions but what the best solution is in your case is hard to tell, because you provided too little context for this.

Comment: yes. I do need generic type arugments as output arguments. yes, I did not mention this, because I treated generic arguments as if they would understand my intention. I was too bogged into solving the domain feature.

Comment: that is exactly what I ended up doing. I disregarded the generic arguments and relied on method arguments types as you suggested. and used a non-generic base for the handler.

but I am not satisfied with the result, I believe this feature will require more freedom. 
> you have to make IRequirementHandler<R, T> covariant. I believe this is exactly what I need for the additional freedom. I need to review the topic of variance and covariance.
thank you for pointing me to the right direction <3